# Javascript function that returns a DOM when input is html content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a Javascript function that returns a correct DOM when input is HTML content.
I have used the follwing function for the same. Here input is HTML content and output is DOM.

```
function htmltoelement(elementHTML)
{   
    var temDiv = document.createElement('div');
    temDiv.innerHTML = elementHTML;        
    return temDiv;
}
```

This function works well for Firefox, but not for IE or Chrome, when the HTML is broken.

I need a suggestion for a function that works fine on all the browsers even when HTML is broken.

Comment: Can you clarify "even when HTML is broken"?  Do you mean the input itself is not valid HTML?

Comment: Why do you expect it to work with broken HTML?

Comment: @J-P - I think the OP *may* mean they're under the impression that `.innerHTML` is broken rather than the input, I think it's a bit ambiguous/needs clarification here.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Yes i mean when html tags are not complete, or there is missing HTML tags. I will give you two examples.

example 1:

<tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

note: Here table tag is missing.


example2:

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Segment AOne. <strong>Segment ATwo. ASegment AThree.</strong></p>
<p><em>Segment BOne.</p>
<p>Segment COne.</em></p>
</head>
</html>


Note: Here em tag is not closed properly

Answer (score 3):

With "broken" HTML (which I am assuming is invalid) the way it is interpreted is largely up to the browser and the mode that the browser is in. The DOCTYPE at the top will dictate how the innerHTML property is parsed when it is set. For XHTML, it will give you some odd results because "broken" HTML will mess up your entire page. The function you are using is correct, but it seems you need to check your input for compliance before attempting to create the div.

Comment: Hey I agree with you, the input is given by user here so I cannot restrict the user to insert only correct HTML. I need a function that works fine even when the HTML is not proper.

Comment: @Dora - There isn't one really, you're feeding a program invalid input, the output will be unpredictable and *very* inconsistent cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by writing it out to a hidden iframe:

```
<iframe id="frame" style="display:none"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">

function htmltoelement(elementHTML)
{   
    var temp = document.getElementById('frame');

    // Cross-browser way to get the iframe document
    var idoc = (temp.contentWindow || temp.contentDocument);
    if (idoc && idoc.document) idoc = idoc.document;

    // Put the HTML in the iframe
    idoc.write("<html><body>" + elementHTML + "</body></html>");
    temDiv = document.createElement('div');
    temDiv.innerHTML = idoc.body.innerHTML;

    return temDiv;
}

document.body.appendChild(htmltoelement('<b><i>hi</b></i>'));

</script>
```

The hidden IFRAME seems to be necessary, document.createElement('iframe') didn't work in Opera.